# YouTube PHP Api v3 Search more information

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

I recently started to use the YouTube Api v3. This allows me to search YouTube Videos. However, I can only get the video id and title. How do I go about getting the uploader id, name, views, length, likes, dislikes, comments, description...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend this link: 
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#part

Review aspects such as "fields", "part"

also CodeAcademy has a great startup course for youtube 
http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/youtube

good luck ^_^

Comment: I have a question. The title is fetched by doing $searchResult['snippet']['title']; However, I try to get the view count by doing this $searchResult['statistics']['viewCount']; and it won't work. Do you know why? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I think you should check out  "yt:statistics"  https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference?csw=1#youtube_data_api_tag_yt%3astatistics                                   It contains the viewCount attribute.

Comment: Glad to help, I just earned 10 points so now I post more than two link in a post(life is complete !!!)